# Estimating the Run Time for the "Traveling Salesman Problem"

Tags: optimization, time, graph, combinations, traveling-salesman

The "Traveling Salesman Problem" is a problem where a person has to travel between "n" cities - but choose the itinerary such that:

- Each city is visited only once
- The total distance traveled is minimized

I have heard that if a modern computer were the solve this problem using "brute force" (i.e. an exact solution) - if there are more than 15 cities, the time taken by the computer will exceed a hundred years!

I am interested in understanding "how do we estimate the amount of time it will take for a computer to solve the Traveling Salesman Problem (using "brute force") as the number of cities increase". For instance, from the following reference (https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/earth-and-planetary-sciences/traveling-salesman-problem):

[image]

**My Question:** Is there some formula we can use to estimate the number of time it will take a computer to solve Traveling Salesman using "brute force"? For example:

- N cities = N! paths
- Each of these N! paths will require "N" calculations
- Thus, N * N calculations would be required for the computer to check all paths and then be certain that the shortest path has been found : If we know the time each calculation takes, perhaps we could estimate the total run time as "time per calculation * N*N! "
- But I am not sure if this factors in the time to "store and compare" calculations.

**Can someone please explain this?**

Answer (score 1):

> I have heard that if a modern computer were the solve this problem using "brute force" (i.e. an exact solution) - if there are more than 15 cities, the time taken by the computer will exceed a hundred years!

This is not completely true. While the naive brute-force algorithm runs with a `n!` complexity. A [much better algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Held%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) using dynamic programming runs in `O(n^2 2^n)`. Just to give you an idea, with n=25, `n! ≃ 2.4e18` while `n^2 2^n ≃ 1e12`. The former is too huge to be practicable while the second could be OK although it should take a pretty long time on a PC (one should keep in mind that both algorithm complexities contain an hidden constant variable playing an important role to compute a realistic execution time). I used an optimized dynamic programming solution based on the Held–Karp algorithm to compute the TSP of 20 cities on my machine with a relatively reasonable time (ie. no more than few minutes of computation).

Note that in practice **heuristics** are used to speed up the computation drastically often at the expense of a *sub-optimal* solution. Some algorithm can provide a good result in a very short time compared to the previous exact algorithms (polynomial algorithms with a relatively small exponent) with a fixed bound on the quality of the result (for example the distance found cannot be bigger than 2 times the optimal solution). In the end, heuristics can often found very good results in a reasonable time. One simple heuristic is to avoid crossing segments assuming an Euclidean distance is used (AFAIK a solution with crossing segments is always sub-optimal).

> My Question: Is there some formula we can use to estimate the number of time it will take a computer to solve Travelling Salesman using "brute force"?

Since the naive algorithm is compute bound and quite simple, you can do such an approximation based on the running-time complexity. But to get a relatively precise approximation of the execution time, you need a *calibration* since not all processors nor implementations behave the same way. You can assume that the running time is `C n!` and find the value of `C` experimentally by measuring the computation time taken by a practical brute-force implementation. Another approach is to theoretically find the value of `C` based on low-level architectural properties (eg. frequency, number of core used, etc.) of the target processor. The former is much more precise assuming the benchmark is properly done and the number of points is big enough. Moreover, the second method requires a pretty good understanding of the way modern processors work.

Numerically, assuming a running time `t ≃ C n!`, we can say that `ln t ≃ ln(C n!) ≃ ln(C) + ln(n!)`. Based on the [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), we can say that `ln t ≃ ln C + n ln n + O(ln n)`, so `ln C ≃ ln t - n ln n - O(ln n)`. Thus, `ln C ≃ ln t - n ln n - O(ln n)` and finally, `C ≃ exp(ln t - n ln n)` (with an `O(n)` approximation). That being said, the Stirling's approximation may not be precise enough. Using a binary search to numerically compute the inverse [gamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html) (which is a generalization of the factorial) should give a much better approximation for `C`.

> Each of these N! paths will require "N" calculations

Well, a slightly optimized brute-force algorithm do not need perform `N` calculation as the partial path length can be precomputed. The last loops just need to read the precomputed sums from a small array that should be stored in the L1 cache (so it take only no more than few cycle of latency to read/store).